# retornando em branco autocomplete

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, autocompletar, .net-core

Faço uma pesquisa no meu banco de dados para buscar o nome dos produtos sem exceções (não sei se é relevante, mas esse retorno é uma lista de string)

```
var listaDosProdutos = _servico.ObterNomeDosProdutos();
```

depois eu pego essa lista e faço uma pesquisa de qual produto começa com o nome digitado e reptorno em formato json

```
var listaFiltroProdutos = listaDosProdutos.Where(str => str.ToLower().StartsWith(Prefix.ToLower())).ToList();
```

código do Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ConsultaProduct(string Prefix)
{
    //Searching records from list using LINQ query
    var listaDosProdutos = _servico.ObterNomeDosProdutos();
    var listaFiltroProdutos = listaDosProdutos.Where(str => str.ToLower().StartsWith(Prefix.ToLower())).ToList();

    return Json(listaFiltroProdutos);
}
```

Dentro da minha camada de _Layout eu estou carregando dois cdn do Jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
</script>
```

e

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Na minha página cshtml eu tenho.
Meu campo input text

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Product", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
{
          <input type="text" class="form-control focus" id="consultarProduto" name="consultarProduto" placeholder="Search by Name, CasNo, Class, Group Name ...">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
```

e meu js

```
$("#consultarProduto").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Product/ConsultaProduct",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.CommercialName, value: item.CommercialName };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

Fiz alguns testes com outros códigos:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525711/asp-net-core-jquery-autocomplete-returns-blank-lines-in-the-list

Porem não tive sucesso.

Comment: Leandro, voce chegou a colocar um debbuger no success do seu Ajax? (gostaria de tornar isso um comentário). Se sim, o retorno da sua lista está sendo devolvido corretamente pelo seu request?

Comment: Ele está retornando um Array com 5 dados, que são os dados que eu esperava que ele iria pegar, mas não sei se ele está retornando para meu request como eu faço?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o erro, aqui no meu código eu estou retornando uma lista de string (não tenho certeza) e estava tentando acessar essa string com:

```
return { label: item.CommercialName, value: item.CommercialName };
```

O que fiz para resolver foi apenas retornar o item dessa forma:

```
return item;
```